# How to use OpenID

Tags: security, authentication, openid, google-openid, openid-connect

I've found blog posts [here](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-openid-connect-basic.html) and [here](http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-a-openid-connect-basic-client-c/) describing how to use OpenID on my website. However, they assume I have a "client identifier" and the url with which to check a user's username+password. How do I get these? And do I need one for each OpenID provider?

[OpenID itself](http://openidexplained.com/developers) only has `recommendations and tips for developers who have already implemented OpenID`.

Note: I am *not* asking how to implement the OpenID API. I'm only asking how to get registered for that.

Comment: you mean how to use OpenID in your client application, right? if that is the case, you definitely do not have to mess with username and passwords - this is all the idea. the OpenID-server deals with it. your app just redirects the request to the server, and hopefully gets a token. So yes, you need OpenID provider (e.g. Google accounts), or you can implement one by your own. p.s note that the docs you have shared are pretty old (2012)...

Comment: you're mixing OpenID Connect and OpenID 2.0 links in your question; I presume you want to do OpenID Connect (only)?

Comment: @HansZ. Yes. I only want the latest. "Connect" as far as I know.

Comment: @OhadR Yes. I have a website and I want to have users login without having to store their passwords. OpenID docs don't seem to exist (except for the specs themselves - too long). How do I start with this?

Comment: there are tons of examples of how to write a web app that uses OpenID... http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Comment: @OhadR I'm not looking for how to write the code. I'm looking for how to get the `client identifier`, `token endpoint`, etc. mentioned in the first link I provided right after `In order for the client to make an OpenID Connect request, it needs to have the following information about the server:`.

Comment: so you are not looking for implementation; you look for the specifications? to understand how the flow works? http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: If you want the latest.  I am using HansZ's mod_auth_openidc, it works quite well.  Other than something like mod_auth_openidc you will need to implement something in your code, there are openidc libraries available for almost all of the popular languages.  As for the client_id, you'll need to get that from whoever is providing the authentication, i.e. if you are going to use Google, you'll need to create an app and register w/ google to get the client ID.  And yes you need one for each OP (OpenIDC provider).